# C# WebBrowser Run Javascript - Return blank page with the result of the Javascript - Why?

Tags: c#, javascript, browser

when i try to run javascript in a webbrowser, the code runs, but after it has been executed takes me on a white page with the upper right corner a numeric value (in this case "1000"), taking me away from the site where I was previously

```
HtmlElement head = webBrowser1.Document.GetElementsByTagName("head")[0];
HtmlElement scriptEl = webBrowser1.Document.CreateElement("script");
IHTMLScriptElement element = (IHTMLScriptElement)scriptEl.DomElement;
element.text = "function ScrollDown() { document.getElementsByClassName('scrollableitemclass').scrollTop = 1000 }";
head.AppendChild(scriptEl);
webBrowser1.Document.InvokeScript("ScrollDown");
```

Thank you for the help

Comment: do you want to scroll to specific element in web-browser control?

Comment: yes, the function works, but after has been executed, webbrowser takes me on a white page with in the upper right corner a numeric value (in this case "1000")

Answer (score 1):

You can scroll to your Html Elemet with [HtmlElement.ScrollIntoView](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.htmlelement.scrollintoview.aspx).

see this example:

```
 public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            webBrowser1.DocumentCompleted += new WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventHandler(webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted);
        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            webBrowser1.DocumentText = "<html><body><span class=\"cls\" id=\"el\"> </body></html>";
        }

        void webBrowser1_DocumentCompleted(object sender, WebBrowserDocumentCompletedEventArgs e)
        {
            //for element with id
            webBrowser1.Document.GetElementById("el").ScrollIntoView(true);
            //for element with spesific
            foreach (HtmlElement el in webBrowser1.Document.All)
            {
                if (el.GetAttribute("ClassName") == "cls")
                {
                    el.ScrollIntoView(true);
                }

            }

        }


    }
```